# How do I set font colour with the PDF::API2 Perl module?

Tags: perl, pdf, fonts

I need to add colour to some text in a PDF document using PDF::API2 - how do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the text color by calling the `fillcolor` method before adding the text:

```
use PDF::API2;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();              # Create a PDF
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica');  # Add a font to the PDF
my $page = $pdf->page();                 # Create a page to hold your text
my $text = $page->text();                # Create a graphics/text object

$text->font($font, 12);                  # Set the font and size for your text
$text->fillcolor('#FF0000');             # Set the text color
$text->text('This text will be red.');   # Add your text
```

Web-style color names will probably work fine in most cases, but you can give a CMYK color instead by using "%" instead of "#" and passing four values (e.g. `%00FF0000` for magenta).

The [PDF::API2::Content](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2/lib/PDF/API2/Content.pm) documentation has more details on the various methods that will affect the `$text` object.

Answer (score 4):

According [PDF::API2::Content](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2/lib/PDF/API2/Content.pm)  it looks like you pass hashref option to *text* method (on a PDF::API::Content::Text object).

So it "should" work like this (NB. I don't have PDF::API2 installed here so code below is untested):

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::API2::Util;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica',-encode=>'latin1');
my $page = $pdf->page;
$page->mediabox( 80, 500 );

my $txt = $page->text;
$txt->font( $font, 20 );

$txt->translate( 50, 800 );
$txt->text('Hello there!', { color => '#e6e6e6' } );  # <= hashref option

$pdf->saveas( "file.pdf" );
$pdf->end();
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 2):

The only options that `$txt->text` supports are -indent, -underline and -strokecolor, though -strokecolor is only used in combination with -underline to determine the color of the line.

Use `$txt->fillcolor('colorname')` or `$txt->fillcolor('#RRGGBB')` to set the color of any text written after the fillcolor command.

Comment: `$txt->fillcolor('...')` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following:

```
my $margin = $x; #co-ordinates for page
my $margin = $y; #co-ordinates for page

my $caption = 'blah blah blah';
my $font=$pdf->corefont('Helvetica-Bold',-encode=>'latin1');
my $font_size = 12;

my $page = $pdf->openpage($pageNum);
my $gfx = $page->gfx;

$gfx->textlabel($margin,$y_pos, $font,$font_size,$caption,
   -color => '#5E5E5E',
);
```

And obviously change hex colour to whatever you want.